# ajax keypress function is not working and the ActionResult parameter is not receiving any value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I want to change(calculate) a textboxs' value on ajax keypress event but the controller ActionResult is not receiving any value to calculate(receiving null)

```
 <script>
    $('#TotDiscnt').keypress(function () {           
        //var data = $('#totDiscnt').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            url: '/Whatever/Discount',
            data: $('#totDiscnt').val(),
            success: function (response) {
                $('#TotPurAmt').val(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

On controller

```
public ActionResult Discount(string text)
    {

       // calculation

        return Json(sum, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I tried as

> data: { text: request.term },

while i do that the the ajax call is not calling the controller method.And one more thing how can i send two double value as a parameter to the ActionResult method form an ajax call as

```
 <script>
$('#TotDiscnt').keypress(function () {           
    //var data = $('#totDiscnt').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        url: '/Whatever/Discount',
        data: {num1:$('#totDiscnt').val(),
                     num2:$('#Discnt').val() },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#TotPurAmt').val(response);
        }
    });
});
```

and then receive as double value in parameter like

```
 public ActionResult Discount(double num1, double num2)
    {
        //calculation

        return Json(sum, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add event either keyup or keypress. You can change your code slightly.

```
<script>
$('#TotDiscnt').keypress(function () {           
    //var data = $('#totDiscnt').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',  //send type of data to sever
        dataType: 'json', //retrun type of data from server
        url: '/Whatever/Discount',
        data: JSON.stringify(text:$(this).val()),

       // data: $('#totDiscnt').val(),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#TotPurAmt').val(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Here your controller should be as.

```
public ActionResult Discount(string text)
{

   // calculation

    return Json(sum, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.
>   For more detail please visit official site [click me](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Please let know in comment is it working or not.

Comment: Is this line of code in correct format "data: {json.stringify( text:$('#totDiscnt').val())},"?
after json. it is saying " : expected ", text: " ) expected" and before } it is saying " ; expected"

Comment: and the ajax is not sending a request at server

Comment: Write inside currly braces.

Comment: still after text: " ) expected" and before , it is saying " ; expected"

Comment: Add inside currly bracea

Comment: still receiving a null value

Comment: Make sure you have write correct controller name . . Try to add attribute [httppost]

Comment: Change keypress to keyup event

Comment: receiving a value but the string length is (length-1)

Comment: Code updated, Yes congratx . .press more than one button . You will numbers of string

Comment: can you please help me with the second portion of the question please?

Comment: Happy coding . . First try urself.

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple value from an ajax call to ActionResults' parameter:
Script:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnCalculate').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: '/Sales/Calculate',
                data: { num1: $('#txtNum1').val(), num2: $('#txtNum2').val(),//so on.... },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#txtSum').val(response)
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and on controller:

```
 public ActionResult Calculate(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        sum = num1 + num2;
        return Json(sum, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```